# jQuery: How do I remove elements from a list <li>

Tags: jquery

I have the following list and would like to remove an  element from it. In this particular instance I would like to remove the second element:

```
<a id="q1" rel="1" class="pagenum" href="#">2</a>
```

And here's the code for the list:

```
        <div id="carousel">
        <ul class="overview">
          <li id="l1">
              <a id="q0" rel="0" class="pagenum" href="#">1</a>
              <a id="q1" rel="1" class="pagenum" href="#">2</a>
              <a id="q2" rel="2" class="pagenum" href="#">3</a>
              <a id="q3" rel="3" class="pagenum" href="#">4</a>
              <a id="q4" rel="4" class="pagenum" href="#">5</a>                
          </li>
         </ul>
        </div>
```

Thanks, in advance.

**EDIT: I was hoping to use something along the lines of $.each:**

```
$("carousel li").each(function(index){
   if(index == SOME_NUM){
       this.remove()
   }
 });
```

However this doesn't seem to work.

**ADDITIONAL EDIT:**

Thanks and apologies to all those who answered. I did not phrase my question correctly. I did find the remove() function prior to posting here - it is well documented on google :). However, I am trying to loop through the elements of the "li" and then remove particular elements via a $.each loop.

Thanks for any and all additional replies.

Comment: Seriously, have you even tried searching for a solution?

Comment: also $('li a').eq(1).remove();

Comment: $("#q1").remove(); http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: uhhh...yea; when I couldn't find one I posted here. Thanks for your contribution, though. Very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do what you want it to do.

```
$counter = 0;
$("#carousel li").each(function(){
    if($counter == SOME_NUM)
    {
        this.remove();
    }
    $counter++;
});
```

You'll want to use jquery $variables here rather than javascript vars because javascript vars are function scoped, while the $variables are document scoped.

Answer (score 4):

ID is unique.. You can simply use `$('#q1').remove();`

Based on your comment

> I was trying to avoid using id as there are a large number of these
>   . I scaled down the example. I was hoping to use something along
>   the lines of: $("overview li").each(function(index){ this.remove }
>   however that doesn't seem to work.

Try using `.eq` function or `:eq` selector to select the specific link tag from the list,

```
$('.overview li a:eq(1)') //-> Will return you the 2nd link
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using id as there are a large number of these <a>. I scaled down the example. I was hoping to use something along the lines of: $("overview li").each(function(index){ this.remove } however that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user580295 You can use `.eq` or `:eq` select on `li a` which will get you the exact link you want. For ex: `$('.overview li a:eq(1)')` -> will return you the 2nd link in the li

Answer (score 1):

Basic form of removal uses [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove):

```
$(selector).remove();
```

So for the second element, you could use the `[id]`:

```
$('#q1').remove();
```

If you want to remove the second item in the list, independent of that item's `[id]`, you could use:

```
$('#l1 :eq(1)').remove();
```

<sub>note that `:eq` uses 0-based indices</sub>

The removal function itself is easy to use, the hard part is determining what [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) works best.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway to use a $.each loop?

Comment: `remove` works for all elements matched in the selection. Please take the time to review the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/), it's ok to be new to jQuery, but you should at least make an effort to look for information on your own.